# Does linux have counters for GRO/GSO?

Tags: networking

I'm doing some work on offloads, and I'm looking at some of the networking offloads (LRO, TSO, GRO and GSO).

All of them can be set on/off by using ([example](https://community.mellanox.com/docs/DOC-2814) for setting LRO on):

```
ethtool -K <interface_name> lro on
```

LRO and TSO have counters that can be viewed by using (again, LRO example):

```
ethtool -S <interface_name> | grep lro
```

But I can't find anywhere a way to check counters on GRO and GSO.
Any idea if these exists, and if so how can I view them?